# Is it possible to use a JavaScript file as a view in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cdn

I'd like for a rails route to point to a javascript file as a view in order to achieve CDN functionality similar to jquery's (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js). Then, users will be able to link their own websites directly to the provided js.

Does anyone have any insight/experience in something like this?

Comment: It's bound to be pretty trivial (I have no Rails experience to speak of or I'd give an answer as an example), but for static file hosting you usually want to avoid involving Rails at all.

Comment: The script will be dynamically generated with input provided by the users. Therefore, I'd like a rails controller to inform the javascript of certain parameters.

Comment: Then it's going to be the same way as you output any other data, except Rails will probably default to outputting a text/html content-type header that you'll need to override to be application/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but you can stream any file you want back to clients.

This is all in the [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) docs.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#options-for-render

E.g.,

```
render file: filename, content_type: "application/javascript"
```